# How do I get code coverage in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm not a developer but found some info on GitHub which gave an Apex class that creates a Quote PDF upon creating the Quote.  I tested in my sandbox and everything works perfectly, however it's telling me I have 0 code coverage so I can't deploy to Prod.  Below are is the Apex and the Test for it.  Any thoughts on what could be wrong?  I followed all the steps in [this](https://automationchampion.com/2021/10/05/generating-a-quote-pdf-using-salesforce-flow/) article which provided the link to the code.

Apex Class

`Public class generateQuotePdfDocument{

```
@InvocableMethod   
public static void CreateQuote(List<Id> quoteIds)  
{ 
    createQuoteFutureMethod(quoteIds);
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void createQuoteFutureMethod (List<Id> quoteIds) {
    //Initialize the quote url
    String quoteUrl = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?';
    
    //Get the Quote Template Id from Custom Settings
    String quoteTemplateId = Label.QuoteTemplateId;
    
    //List variable to get all the Quote Documents
    List<QuoteDocument> lstQuoteDoc = new List<QuoteDocument>();
    
    if(!quoteIds.isEmpty() && quoteIds.size() > 0) {
        
        for(Id quoteId :quoteIds) {
            //Construct the quote URL to generate PDF
            quoteUrl += 'id=' + quoteId;
            quoteUrl += '&headerHeight=197&footerHeight=10';
            quoteUrl += '&summlid=' + quoteTemplateId;
            
            //call the quote url
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(quoteUrl);
            
            //get the quotePdf
            Blob quoteBlob;
            
            if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
                quoteBlob = Blob.valueOf('Generate Pdf');
            } else {
                quoteBlob = pageRef.getContentAsPDF();
            }
            
            //initialze the QuoteDocument to hold the quote pdf for insertion
            QuoteDocument quoteDoc = new QuoteDocument();
            quoteDoc.Document = quoteBlob;
            quoteDoc.QuoteId = quoteId;
            lstQuoteDoc.add(quoteDoc);
        }
    }
    
    if(!lstQuoteDoc.isEmpty() && lstQuoteDoc.size() > 0) {
        Database.insert(lstQuoteDoc);
    }
    
}
```

}`

Test Class

`` `@istest ``
`private class generateQuotePdfDocumentTest {`

`@testSetup`
`static void setup() {`

`Product2 product = new Product2();`
`product.Name = 'Test Product ';`
`product.ProductCode = '123';`
`product.IsActive = true;`
`insert product;`

`PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();`
`pbe.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();`
`pbe.Product2Id = product.Id;`
`pbe.IsActive = true;`
`pbe.UnitPrice = 10;`
`insert pbe;`

`Opportunity op = new Opportunity();`
`op.Name = 'Test';`
`op.Type = 'Value Proposition';`
`op.Amount= 1200;`
`op.CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(2);`
`op.StageName = 'Created';`

`insert op;`

`Quote quote = new Quote();`
`quote.OpportunityId = op.Id;`
`quote.Name = 'TestQuote';`
`quote.ExpirationDate = Date.today().addDays(5);`
`quote.Status = 'Draft';`
`quote.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();`
`insert quote;`

`QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem();`
`qli.QuoteId = quote.Id;`
`qli.Quantity = 2;`
`qli.PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id;`
`qli.UnitPrice = 20;`
`insert qli;`
`}`

`@isTest`
`static void generateQuotePdfTest() {`

`Quote quote = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Quote LIMIT 1];`

`quote.Status = 'Draft';`
`update quote;`
`}`

`` }` ``

In my attempt to deploy to production I realized my code coverage was 0.  So I'm trying to learn how to correct this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your code in your test method.

Sorry on my phone but something like

```
Test.startTest;
  Generatequotepfddpcument.createquote(new list<id>{quote.id};
 Test.StopTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this invocable method in your class "CreateQuote"? I guess the the update you are doing in your test class is not firing that invocable method hence the 0 coverage. Try making the update so that the condition matches in your test class for firing the invocable method.